# SD card interfacing using spi

Tags: spi

hi friends
i want to interface SD card using spi.i have no idea on this topic e.g how to initialize,how to work .please help completely about spi SD card interfacing 
Thanks

Answer (score 9):

The MMC card and the SD card are flash memory storage based devices, and are physically very similar. Both card types support proprietary data transfer protocols using four data bits, and are compatible though having different initialisation. The major difference is that the SD card is designed to provide optional security by allowing encryption of the device contents. The MMC card supports additional bus widths (up to 8 bits). The SD card also supports several modes that are not present in the MMC card, including SDIO (secure digital input/output) that can be used as an external communications interface using the standard SD card format.
Both card types also support a basic SPI type interface for simple connection to embedded devices. The SD card specifications state a maximum clock frequency of 25MHz, and the MMC specifications state a maximum clock frequency of 52MHz depending on the device. Figure 1 shows the MMC/SD card connections when configured for SPI mode operation.

Here are some useful links on SPI:

1. [Wikipedia help page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus)
2. [Detect SD Card, Read/Write to Card, in VB 2005](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=505026)
3. [writing data to sd card](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=416146)
4. [A pdf on Theories of SD and SPI together](http://www.cyantechnology.com/public/AN037InterfacingtoanMMCorSDCardviaSPI.pdf)
5. [SD Card Specification Details](http://downloads.amilda.org/MODs/SDCard/SD.pdf)